# datepicker not defined - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datepicker

I have created a django application. In my application i have a registration from which has a date field.For that i was using jQuery datepicker. It was working fine before, but today when i started my application its not working for some unknown reason. I am not able to understand why its not working in my code, but works fine when i gave that script alone in a new html. The error it shows now is datepicker is not a function.Can somebody look into this. I will paste my html code here.

html

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<title>Login/Registration Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

   //Created / Generates the captcha function    
    function DrawCaptcha()
    {
        var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
        var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';       
        var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
        var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
        document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code
    }

    // Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function   
    function ValidCaptcha(){
        var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
        var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
        if (str1 == str2) return true;        
        return false;

    }

    // Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
    function removeSpaces(string)
    {
        return string.split(' ').join('');
    }

    </script>
<body bgcolor="#736F6E" onLoad="DrawCaptcha();">
<div align="center">
<form name="userInputForm" method="POST" id="myFormid" action="http://10.1.0.90:8080/login/">
  <div style="float:left;width:100%;">
    <p style="float:left;margin-right:10px;width:auto;">
      <label style="float:left;">Email id</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="username" size="25" />
    </p>
    <p style="float:left;margin-right:10px;width:auto;">
      <label style="float:left;">Password</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="password" name="password" size="25" />
      {% if invalid %}
      Mismatch in your email/password. 
      {% endif %} </p>
  </div>

  <p style="clear:both;float:left;">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" style="float:left;margin-right:4px;"/>&nbsp;


{% load facebookconnect %}
{% facebook_connect_login_button %}
{% facebook_connect_script %}


    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a HREF="http://10.1.0.90:8080/forgotPassword/">Forgotten your password?</a></p>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
function userCheck(){
    /*document.getElementById('myFormid').action = "http://10.1.0.90:8080/login/";
    if ((document.userInputForm.username.value.length==0)) */
}
</script>
<form name ="myform"  method="POST" id='FormID'>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" value=""  maxlength="100" />
      <b id="firstNameID" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" value="" maxlength="100" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-mail</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" maxlength="100" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="100"  />
      <b id="passwordID" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Re-Type Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password1" value="" maxlength="100"  />
      <b id="passwordID1" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gender:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
      Male
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
      Female </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="birthday" id="datepicker" value="" maxlength="100" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  <td width="150">Captcha</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtCaptcha" 
            style="background-image:url(1.jpg); text-align:center; border:1px;
            font-weight:bold; font-family:Modern" />
      <input type="button" id="btnrefresh" value="Refresh" onClick="DrawCaptcha();" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter above text</td>
        <td style="float:left;"><input type="text" id="txtInput" value="" maxlength="100" />
      <b id="textcaptcha" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<div style="width:200; float:left; margin:20px 0 0 155px;">
  <input type="button" value="Sign Up" onClick="isEmpty();"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isEmpty(){
    if  ((document.myform.firstName.value.length==0)) 
        {
        document.getElementById('firstNameID').innerHTML = 'Please fill this field';
        return true;
        }
    else if ((document.myform.password.value.length==0)) 
        {
        document.getElementById('passwordID').innerHTML = 'Please fill this field';
        return true;
        }
    else if (document.myform.password.value != document.myform.password1.value)
        {
        document.getElementById('passwordID1').innerHTML = 'Password mismatch';
        return true;
        }
    else if (! ValidCaptcha())
        {
            document.getElementById('textcaptcha').innerHTML = 'Please fill the captcha correctly';
        }

    else 
        { 
        document.getElementById('FormID').action = "http://10.1.0.90:8080/registrationForm/";
        document.getElementById('FormID').submit();
        return false; 
        }
}
</script><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you change the calling anonymous function that creates the datepicker, so it's not `$(document).ready()`? This kind've stands out to me, without further review.

Comment: i didnt get you..Can you please paste me that code. I am a newbie in programming

Comment: Obviously the onload handlers registered using the ready() method are not executed. Very little to read from your code without having further details.First take your favorite JS debugging tool like Firebug and check for JS errors yourself - then report back. Don't expect that we can read remote your error messages. Take your time and provide reasonable and precise error information.

Comment: the error thrown is 'datepicker is not a function' .

Comment: @rv_k - I gave it a shot; I wasn't aware that $(function(){}) is the same as $(document).ready(). If your error is that datepicker isn't found, I'd try Firebug in FF to see if the UI class is loading correctly from Google.

Comment: @ Jared : yes, its loading. I tried the datepicker script alone in a fresh html and its working fine. But when i put it in my above html, its not working.

Comment: @rv_k - What line exactly is it reporting the problem? (Look at the result page, not the server script.)

Comment: @rv_k What's the full error message? Are there any other errors or warnings? Open the Firefox error console and reload the page

Comment: @ Jared :This is the error: $("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function     
http://10.1.0.90:8080/registrationForm/     
Line 16

Comment: What's on line 16? Of the page source?

Comment: @rv_k - You should check in Firebug that the jquery UI script is actually loading. Do this by selecting it on the Script tab; see if you have a 404 error or whatnot.

Comment: on line 16 of page source its 'changeYear:True' statement inside the jQuery function

Comment: Your pasted code is working for me.  I'm not clear on which part is not working for you.

Comment: for me its throwing an error 'datepicker is not a function' :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed.. It was a small ignorance from my side. The jqury.js file was referred in another page which was extended from `{% facebook_connect_script %}` . Thanks a lot for you guys help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is related to your issue or not, but you have some invalid HTML in the code snippet you've posted. I would start by making sure all of your tags are balanced, you have a second form tag that doesn't get closed. Also, you have several bold tags in your table that are not closed as well.

Comment: i have closed the form tag. Again its throwing the same error.

Comment: When I open the posted code inside of Chrome, Firefox, and IE I don't see the error your encountering and the jQuery datepicker appears to be functioning for me. The issue is likely coming from something else that wasn't in the pasted code.

Comment: no..i pasted the same working code of mine..why is it throwing such error just for me ? :(

Comment: Are you including any other javascript libraries that make use of `$`? Try utilizing jQuery's [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode and see if that resolves the issue.